# Converting .ecw to .jp2

Tags: qgis, convert, software-recommendations, ecw, jpeg-2000

Is there any easy to use software for converting .ecw/.eww files to .jp2/.jpw files without loosing the georeferencing? I don't want to use proprietary file formats with QGIS.

EDIT: I've deleted the question if the performance of .jp2 files is comparable to .ecw files.

Comment: Do you want the georeferencing [incorporated into the jp2 file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000#GML_JP2_georeferencing), or is having 'sidecar' world files acceptable? Most GIS software should be capable of exporting a jp2 with a world file for it, but I don't know if they all have the capability to properly embed the location information in the jp2 itself.

Comment: I've got .ecw and .eww files, so .jp2 and .jpw would be okay. If possible I don't want to install the closed ECW libraries for QGis.Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with it to say for certain, but you might look at GDAL. It make take some supplemental libraries to work with ECW or embed the georeferencing info as well. You may want to **edit** your question to include that you are ok with having world files or embedding the info into the jp2.

Comment: You will see in the [Tour] that there should be only one question asked per question so I recommend that you edit your second one out and research/ask it separately. However, having been involved in some related benchmarking I know that the answer will depend on how you measure fast and what software you use to access the two formats. Consequently, you will need to spend some time defining "fast" to avoid asking a question likely to attract diverging opinions.

Comment: Just be aware that if you create JP2s,  you will still need to use proprietary libraries to use them as the only open option (openjpeg) is extremely slow. You might be better off with ycbcr compressed geotiffs

Comment: OpenJPEG is relatively fast but big images must be created as tiled. 1024x1204 tile size is OK.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the (proprietary) ECW format, you'll have to use the proprietary libraries. Using GDAL to convert them will only work if you have the proprietary ECW libraries [installed and configured in GDAL](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ECW). There are other applications that read ECW (e.g. Global Mapper), but I believe they all use the proprietary libraries, and most of them are also proprietary.

It may be possible to find an alternative source of the data (e.g. whatever the ECW files were produced from), but that will obviously depend on where you got the data, and whether the originator is willing or able to make some alternative formats available.

JP2 is (as you've identified) a file format (perhaps better considered as a compression method, but conventions apply to make it a file format), and a file format doesn't have any inherent speed characteristics. Speed is a function of what you're using to read it, and individual file characteristics, and that can obviously vary.

Both ECW and JP2 have their advantages and disadvantages, and you'd need to explain much more about your specific scenarios for us to advise further (hint, another question).

There are some alternative formats (e.g. NITF is sometimes used for remote sensing) that encapsulate JPEG2000 images and provide a lot of metadata, including georeferencing. You could investigate those.